# Jenkins sidecar approach - running multiple containers inside main container

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, sidecar

I 'm trying to replicate the sidecar approach in Jenkins from here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers but I 'm trying to run multiple containers inside.
my code looks something like this:

```
PG_IMG = 'custom_postgres:dev'
PG_NAME = 'db'
script.docker.withRegistry('https://index.docker.io/v1/', 'dockerHub'){
    script.docker.image(PG_IMG).withRun('-p 5432:5432'){c ->
        script.docker.image(PG_IMG).inside("--link ${c.id}:${PG_NAME}"){
           script.sh("echo ======= db ======")
          }
        script.docker.image('redis').inside("-d --link ${c.id}:${PG_NAME}"){
           script.sh("echo ======= redis ======")
         }
        script.docker.image('python:3.6').inside("-u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --link ${c.id}:'${PG_NAME}'") {
           script.sh("apt-get update -qq && apt-get install curl -y && curl --silent -SL https://get.docker.com/ | sh")
           script.sh("docker ps -a")
        }
    }
}
```

I 'm then trying to list all the containers that are running the in VM via python container by setting up docker.sock, but the 'docker ps -a' command output shows only two containers as up and running and there is no info about redis image (not even in exited state) but from Jenkins logs I could see that redis image is getting pulled.
I 'm not able get what I 'm missing here and why redis container isn't listed in 'docker ps -a' command.
Any help and suggestions will be really helpful